# how to filter rsyslog messages by tags

Tags: bash, logging, syslog, rsyslog

I have several applications and scripts that I want to redirect the output to custom files.

I launch those applications using

```
command | logger -t TAG
```

I would like to filter these messages based on their tags and redirect them to different files.
I don't want to use bash redirection as those applications are mainly long running process and need proper log rotation.

I have tried to add a custom filter in /etc/rsyslog.d/60-myfilter.conf ;

```
if $syslogtag == 'giomanager' then /var/log/giomanager.log
```

What am I doing wrong ? 
What is the proper way to filter based on the tag or is there a better option to have similar result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I finally found a solution to my problem.

Thank you very much to @lain for leading my way.

The solution as stated before is to include a ':' in the tag name. Also, and this is very important, the file name must be before `50-default.conf` in alphabetical order.

To resume, put the following in `30-giomanager.conf` :

```
:syslogtag, isequal, "giomanager:" /var/log/giomanager.log
& stop
```

Note that the file `/var/log/giomanager.log` should be writable by the 'syslog' user.

Comment: Thanks @mistyrouge. I have the same problem you had. After logging into correct file my logs are being redirected to /var/log/syslog. Do you have an idea why this is happening and how to prevent it ?

Comment: I couldn't get this to work for filtering bind9 logs. Instead, ':programname, isequal, "named" /var/log/named/named.log' works. Probably because the tag is like "named[32193]".

Comment: You can use `startswith` instead of `isequal` if, for example, the tag contains a PID.  Or `regex` for complex matches.

Answer (score 25):

I've not used if like that (or syslogtag) but I have used `:<blah>,<condition> ...` (in particular :msg, contains,...) but try

```
:syslogtag, isequal, "giomanager:" /var/log/giomanager.log
& stop
```

The `& stop` (Or, `& ~` in rsyslog v6 and older (Such as on RHEL6)) causes the matched message to be discarded after logging otherwise it will be further parsed by other rules.

---

Update: tested and

The syslogtag contains a `:` and should be enclosed in `""` rather than `''`

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I just tried what you propose, indeed the message gets discarded but is never written to `/var/log/giomanager.log`

Comment: @mistyrouge: see my update

Comment: Thank you very much, I now have my log redirected to `/var/log/giomanager.log` **but** it is still written to /var/log/syslog. Do you have an idea why this is happening and how to prevent it ?

Comment: discard action (~ indicator) is deprecated: has been replaced by the (better) alternative "stop" statement: http://kb.monitorware.com/kbeventdb-detail-id-7171.html

Comment: Since the tag in the log may eventually have a pid attached, the tag will be `giomanager[12334]:`. In this case the given rule won't work. I replaced the rule with the following one which works in presence and absence of the pid. `:syslogtag, contains, "giomanager"`.

Answer (score -1):

[This redhat document](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/s1-basic_configuration_of_rsyslog) describes how to filter rsyslog logs and output them to separate files, even dynamic file names in great detail.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged here, since links rot. I've had some of my old answers rot this way. Please add some context and part of the solution to this answer so it can stand alone to future searchers.

Comment: Link is now 404.

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/s1-basic_configuration_of_rsyslog