# Unable to log into a rsyslog filter using logger

Tags: linux, logging, rsyslog

Ubuntu 64 14.04 comes with rsyslog (7) built-in.

I've added `test.conf` to `/etc/rsyslog.d` with the following line:

```
:syslogtag,isequal,"test"       /var/log/test.log
```

I then restart rsyslog and log using `logger`:

```
echo "hi there" | logger -t test
```

I expect that line to reach `/var/log/test.log`, but instead it reaches `syslog.log`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a colon after test.  It reads `"test"` but should read `"test:"`.

This is the same issue:  [how to filter rsyslog messages by tags](https://serverfault.com/questions/514901/how-to-filer-rsyslog-messages-by-tags).

Comment: I've disabled all rules in the rsyslog.d dir and left only the above test rule. Restarted rsyslog. Nothing reaches test.log (nor does anything reach syslog, naturally). I've tried specifying `-p user.notice` but it did not make a difference.

Comment: I misread part of your question and didn't notice you were trying to route based on the tag.  The commonly accepted practice is to use the facility to route syslog messages.  I think you'll find that much more straightforward.  That said, I think your problem is you're missing a colon in `"test"`.  It should be `"test:"`.  See: [how to filer rsyslog messages by tags](http://serverfault.com/questions/514901/how-to-filer-rsyslog-messages-by-tags).

Comment: That was it. Thanks. (if you edit your answer to update it I'd be happy to accept it)