# Pass host from nginx to rsyslog

Tags: nginx, debian, syslog, rsyslog

I have a cluster of nginx web servers and a separate syslog server running rsyslog. The nginx vhost looks like this:

```
access_log      syslog:server=10.0.0.51,facility=local1,severity=info combined;
error_log       syslog:server=10.0.0.51,facility=local2 debug;
```

And the custom rsyslog config like this:

```
$template access_log,"/var/syslog/%HOSTNAME%/%PROGRAMNAME%/access.log"
$template error_log,"/var/syslog/%HOSTNAME%/%PROGRAMNAME%/error.log"
local1.*        -?access_log
local2.*        -?error_log
```

It works great but I would like to create separate log files on rsyslog for the different vhosts, so, e.g.,

/var/syslog/my-hostname/nginx/example.org-access.log

/var/syslog/my-hostname/nginx/somedomain.com-access.log

And so on. How can I pass the host from nginx to rsyslog?

Answer (score 1):

Not able to comment, but maybe this will get you started in the right direction.

Nginx allows you to set tags for each log.  From the documentation for [nginx syslog](http://nginx.org/en/docs/syslog.html):

> *tag=string*
>
> Sets the tag of syslog messages. Default is “nginx”.

For example I have this in my config:

```
access_log      syslog:server=server,tag=nginx_access;
```

For your site configuration you can set access and error logs per virtual server:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name foo1.local;
    location /var/www/site1;
    access_log      syslog:server=server,tag=nginx_access_site1;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name foo2.local;
    location /var/www/site2;
    access_log      syslog:server=server,tag=nginx_access_site2;
}
```

Now you should be able to filter these messages based on the tags.  From [How to filter rsyslog messages by tags](https://serverfault.com/questions/514901/how-to-filter-rsyslog-messages-by-tags) you can set up a configuration file:

```
:syslogtag, isequal, "nginx_access_site1:" /var/syslog/my-hostname/nginx/site1-access.log
& stop

:syslogtag, isequal, "nginx_access_site2:" /var/syslog/my-hostname/nginx/site2-access.log
& stop
```

You also need to make sure that whatever you call this config file, it needs to get loaded before your default configs (which seems to be 50-default.conf) - so for example you could name it 20-nginx.conf.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not scalable as I would have to add a new tag filter to rsyslog for every vhost. I tried to use the tag for simply passing the host, but it only allows alphanumeric characters and underscore, thus some-example.com would not be allowed.